# EXCEL How to set a cell to a specific color based on a formula that involves another worksheet?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two worksheets, the first has cells with numbers in them (A2, B2, C3) which represent the GRADE the student got for a specific question. The second has cells that define the PASSING GRADE for each question

What I need to do, for each cell in the first worksheet (call it $Grades$) is to do something like this:

A2 = if value in A2 is greater then passing Grade for Q1 on Worksheet $passing$ then color A2 Green, else color A2 red.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the passing grade given? Is it at the top of the row in $passing$ or is it in each cell?

Comment: Passing grade is in another worksheet with form (A1) Q1 (B1) 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to another worksheet in conditional formatting formulas (this would have been the easiest solution - try it, excel will throw error)

There is a simple way around that however - Named Ranges!

**Step 1:**

Go to your worksheet that contains the pass marks. 
[Here I assume the following layout for this sheet:]

```
    [A] [B] [C] [D] [E] [F]
[1] Q1  Q2  Q3  Q3  Q4  Q5
[2] 20  20  30  30  50  80
[3]
```

Select range A1:F2 and go to Formulas->Defined Names->Create from selection->top row ticked -> ok
then click "Name Manager"you will see a list of your names ranges (Q1_ = 20, Q2_ =20 etc..).

Keep note of the names, and close the box

**Step 2:**

- go to your sheet with scores.
- select all cells containing scores. format them with red fill.
- select all cells containing marks for question 1 (for all students)
- click on Conditional Formatting -> new rule.. -> format only cells that contain...
- select "cell value " + "greater than" and in the box on he end type (without quotes) "=Q1_" (make sure there are no quotes within the box)
- select your format (green fill) and click ok.

repeat for other questions

If you change the pass mark on the second sheet formats should auto-update